# UILabel alignment to other UILabels

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a cell prototype that i'm trying to add two labels to. I have the two labels right next to each other, but the size of the labels are dynamic, so I want the second label to be able to shift depending on the size of the first label.

Basically, I want there to be a fixed gap between the two labels, but the two labels' sizes are dynamic.

How do I do that?

EDIT:

Actually I found out how to do it via Storyboard. If you select the two labels you want to have a fixed gap between, just command select both of them and then go to the corner of storyboard and click the pin menu, which is that little 'H' looking thing in the group of buttons near zoom in/zoom out in the bottom right corner of the storyboard screen.

Answer (score 1):

Get the label size by this method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html.

Then set label's textAlignment to NSTextAlignmentLeft and NSTextAlignmentRight, and set frames by the string size and other offset.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView -sizeThatFits:` and `-sizeToFit` will allow you to manually calculate a position for the second label.  This is slightly more accurate than using the `NSString` method, as there's more to a `UILabel` than just the text — this will respect content insets, etc.